# How do I apply the definition of stability to this sample problem?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The definition of stability according to my textbook:

A solution $\phi(t)$ of $y' = f(t,y)$ is said to be stable if:

> For every $\epsilon >0$ and every $t_0 \geq 0$ there exists a
>   $\delta >0$ such that whenever $|\phi(t_0) - y_0| < \delta$, the
>   solution $\psi(t, t_0, y_0)$ exists for $t \geq t_0$ and satisfies
>   $|\phi(t) - \psi(t)| < \epsilon$

I'm trying to apply this definition to some sample problems. I'm attempting to use the definition directly, sort of like I was taught in my introduction to analysis classes: Find a way to define $\delta (\epsilon)$ that makes the inequality true.

**Example:** $y' = y$, $\phi(t) = e^t$

**My work:**

Find $\psi(t, t_0, y_0) = y_0e^{t-t_0}$

Let $|\phi(t_0) - y_0| = |e^{t_0} - y_0| < \delta$

Then $|\phi(t) - \psi(t,t_0, y_0)| = |e^t - y_0e^{t-t_0}| = e^{t-t_0}|e^{t_0} - y_0| \leq e^{t-t_0} \delta \lt \epsilon$

But since the solution exists for all $t\geq 0$, It doesn't seem like we can bound the whole inequality by an arbitrary epsilon no matter how we choose $\delta$.

Does this mean that $\phi(t)$ is unstable?

Also, is using this sort of "analysis" the easiest method of answering questions like this? There are no examples in the textbook, so I am using a technique from a different class.

**EDIT:**
There are problems involving higher order ODEs as well:

$y'' + 4y = 0$,  $\phi(t) \equiv 0$

On this one, It's easy to reduce the system and analyze the eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix. In this case, we have two complex eigenvalues with no real parts. The system is linear, and so we have that the origin is a center and is stable. But, I have no idea how I would have arrived at that conclusion by using the epsilon/delta definition provided in the textbook.